# How to solve problem "Cannot open camera from website"

Tags: android

I using android studio to build a simple apps. I want to open camera from the website. I using web fragment to access the website. From the website have one button to open camera, but when I open from my apps failed to open the camera. It will show this this:
[image]

I already open the permission for camera. Anyone can help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: do you want to *play video form website*, or *stream your device's camera to website*?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I want to stream mydevice's camera to website

Comment: WebView does not support it by default as I know.

Comment: If not using webView can stream camera to website?

Comment: you can just perform same operations as browser performs - capture the video and send it the same way as the browser

Comment: Can I know how to do it? What component need to use?

Comment: totally depends on how it works on the web site

Comment: oh okay, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    });
```